# group dataframe based on columns

Tags: python, dataframe, data-science

I am new to datascience your help is appreciated. my question is regarding grouping dataframe based on columns so that bar chart will be plotted based on each subject status

my csv file is something like this

```
Name,Maths,Science,English,sports
S1,Pass,Fail,Pass,Pass
S2,Pass,Pass,NA,Pass
S3,Pass,Fail,Pass,Pass
S4,Pass,Pass,Pass,NA
S5,Pass,Fail,Pass,NA
```

expected o/p:

```
Subject,Status,Count
Maths,Pass,5
Science,Pass,2
Science,Fail,3
English,Pass,4
English,NA,1
Sports,Pass,3
Sports,NA,2
```

Comment: Do you need to create new rows for missing data: `Maths,Fail,0` which does not exist in the original frame? Also, why would you add `Fail` when they are missing from the original frame and not `NA` when they too are missing from the original frame - e.g., `Maths,NA,0`?

Comment: Agree.Each subject can have 3 statuses in my requirement "Pass","Fail","NA". If all students are passed in subject Maths then the Fail count need not be populated in result. I m correcting my o/p. NA is the status when certain subject is not applicable for student.

Comment: maybe the function pandas.melt() can help you, take a look: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with pandas, not exactly in the same output format in the question, but definitely having the same information:

```py
import pandas as pd

# reading csv
df = pd.read_csv("input.csv")

# turning columns into rows
melt_df = pd.melt(df, id_vars=['Name'], value_vars=['Maths', 'Science', "English", "sports"], var_name="Subject", value_name="Status")

# filling NaN values, otherwise the below groupby will ignore them.
melt_df = melt_df.fillna("Unknown")

# counting per group of subject and status.
result_df = melt_df.groupby(["Subject", "Status"]).size().reset_index(name="Count")
```

Then you get the following result:

```
   Subject   Status  Count
0  English     Pass      4
1  English  Unknown      1
2    Maths     Pass      5
3  Science     Fail      3
4  Science     Pass      2
5   sports     Pass      3
6   sports  Unknown      2
```

Answer (score 0):

PS: Going forward, always paste code on what you've tried so far

To match exactly your output, this is what you could do:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('c:/temp/data.csv') # Or where ever your csv file is

subjects = ['Maths', 'Science' , 'English' , 'sports'] # Or you could get that as df.columns and drop 'Name'
grouped_rows = []
for eachsub in subjects:
    rows = df.groupby(eachsub)['Name'].count()
    idx = list(rows.index)
    if 'Pass' in idx:
        grouped_rows.append([eachsub, 'Pass', rows['Pass']])
    if 'Fail' in idx:
        grouped_rows.append([eachsub, 'Fail', rows['Fail']])
new_df = pd.DataFrame(grouped_rows, columns=['Subject', 'Grade', 'Count'])
print(new_df)
```

I must suggest though that I would avoid getting into the for loop. My approach would be just these two lines:

```
subjects = ['Maths', 'Science' , 'English' , 'sports'] 
grouped_rows = df.groupby(eachsub)['Name'].count()
```

Depending on your application, you already have the data available in grouped_rows